# Can't access local server url (my-computer.local) on android tablet

Tags: android, networking, config

I have configured a local URL on my mac (http://my-computer.local) to access a server I host on my mac, on a local WIFI network (offline).
I can access my server with this URL using other desktop computers and iPhones, but not on Android devices.
On the Chrome browser of my android tablets/phone I get the page:

> You are Offline
>
> ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

However, when I type the server's IP address directly in the same browser on the Android tablet, it works.

Why is the local URL not working only on the Android device and how can I solve this, and get it to work?

Comment: What has your mac to do with this all? And you did not tell where your server is running. And please suply full urls.

Comment: Edited to make it clearer, the server is hosted on the mac.

Comment: So the network used is same in all devices?

Comment: What kind of server? And full urls pleasel Why has this to be asked twice? And what is 'configuring a local url on a mac'?

Comment: @rach8garg yes, in this case all the mentioned devices are connected to the same wifi network.